# Updating UI concurrently on iOS

Tags: ios5, user-interface, concurrency, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have two scroll views in my app, one containing UIImageViews, one containing UIButtons. Using NSTimer, I'm making them scroll automatically. However, if one of the scroll views is tampered with (a finger touches it and starts scrolling manually), the other scroll view stops as well. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Or is it normal?

Also, the UIButtons inside the second scroll view are tap-able, but they don't show the standard highlighting. If I enable the glow effect, it works, but not the standard highlighting. Is there anyway I can make this work as well?

My code for NSTimer is

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.018 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(onTimerScrollText) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];

- (void)onTimerScrollText {
    CGFloat x = self.textScroller.contentOffset.x;

    x += 0.5;

    [self.textScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0)];
}
```

And it's pretty much the same for the image scroller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem of one scrollview no longer scrolling until the other manual scroll has finished has been solved.

The solution is simple. Each timer needs to be added to the run loop:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Now they both work regardless of whether one is interrupted by one's finger.